# Iterate Object Val

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I've got a food json file that i grab multiple values from. My issue is that I am able to iterate over the arrays as well as the objects however, for example the directions are not always the same amount of steps for different recipes. I want to create these as li in html but its just storing as one large string. I want to be able to create an individual li for each step not one li for all the steps...

What i Ive tried that has worked is array[index] - however as Ive said I want to be able to iterate through each one and create it as its own li as not all recipe directions are the same number of steps.

```
function getJson() {
    fetch("url")
    .then(function(res){
       return res.json();
})
    .then(function(data){

        let ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);

        const directions = Object.entries(data[ran].directions);

        let newDirections = [];

        for(const [count, direction] of directions) {
            newDirections.push(count, direction);
        }

        document.getElementById('recipe').innerHTML = `
        <h1>${data[ran].name}</h1>
        <p>${data[ran].description}</p>
        <img src='${data[ran].image}'>
        <h3>Directions: </h3>
        <li>${newDirections}</li>
        `;

    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

everything works fine, no errors. However what i want is for "newDirections" in the litteral string to create an li for each step/direction in this case well say 4 steps. I want 4 individual li's listing each of their steps not 1 li with everything in it

this is what it looks like...

[image]

however there are 4 steps in this example and i want them to be under their own li's

Comment: We also need to see the object/array (after its converted to from json) aka the value of `data`.

Comment: I went ahead and added an image of what its showing.